# Is there a command to wait X seconds before next command?

Tags: bash, terminal

Say I want to execute two commands but I want to wait X amount of seconds before the next one gets executed, what's the command for this?

E.g. `sudo dnf upgrade -y && [PAUSE X SECONDS] && shutdown -r`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sleep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sleep.1.html)

```
sudo dnf upgrade -y && sleep x && shutdown -r
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Remember && is a conditional: if the upgrade fails (non-zero status) then the system will neither wait not shut down. It will just prompt for the next command.

Comment: Hmmm... how would I make this unconditional? I.e. to execute a reboot only if changes have been made?

Comment: @telometto: That is what you are doing now, I don't know why Paul said anything.